# A statement in sympy is returning false when it shouldn't be

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, symbolic-math

For context: I'm using sympy in python 2.7. Part of my project involves simplifying a mathematical expression, but I ran into a problem when using sympy:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols ("x")
(-x*exp(-x) + exp(-x)) == (1-x)*(exp(-x))
```

the code above returns me

```
False
```

Both my own maths and wolframalpha disagree with this - did I type something wrong or is this some shortcoming of sympy that I'm not yet aware of?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs page:
http://docs.sympy.org/dev/gotchas.html

> If you want to test for symbolic equality, one way is to subtract one expression from the other and run it through functions likeexpand(), simplify(), and trigsimp() and see if the equation reduces to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a symbolic equality, use `Eq`:

```
In [1]: Eq((-x*exp(-x) + exp(-x)), (1-x)*(exp(-x)))
Out[1]: 
     -x    -x             -x
- x⋅ℯ   + ℯ   = (-x + 1)⋅ℯ
```

The `==` operator has to immediately return a boolean expression, this is a Python standard. Therefore the `==` operator matches the rude structure of the expressions without performing any mathematical transformation (apart from previous minor automatic transformations happening at the expression construction).